# Performance when reader and writer thread on ConcurrentHashMap same sagement

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashtable, concurrenthashmap

In an interview the interviewer asked me how ConcurrentHashMap different than HashTable. I just want to discuss the point on which the interviewer was not convinced. I said in ConcurrentHashMap any number of thread can perform read operation simultaneously whereas in HashTable only one thread at a time. Then he given a scenario for ConcurrentHashMap suppose one thread is writing on one segment and at the same time another thread is reading it's value would the second thread is blocked?? I said no but he was not convinced. I checked in javadoc which says..

Retrieval operations (including  get) generally do not
block, so may overlap with update operations (including put
and remove). Retrievals reflect the results of the most
recently completed update operations holding upon their
onset.

It says Retrieval operations do not block but added `generally` what is this mean??

For this I made a program where two threads performing reading and writing operation on ConcurrentHashMap and HashTable and also with synchronizedMap:
I am performing reading and writing operation on same segment for one second

```
class ReaderThread extends Thread {

    private Map<String, Integer> map;
    private static boolean b = false;

    public ReaderThread(Map<String, Integer> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public void run() {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        long endTime = 0;
        while (!b) {
            map.get("A");
            endTime = System.nanoTime();
            if (endTime - startTime > 1000000000L)
                b = true;
        }
    }
}

class WriterThread extends Thread {

    private Map<String, Integer> map;
    private static int n = 0;
    private static boolean b = false;

    public WriterThread(Map<String, Integer> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

    public void run() {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        long endTime = 0;
        while (!b) {
            map.put("A", n++);
            endTime = System.nanoTime();
            if (endTime - startTime > 1000000000L)
                b = true;
        }
    }
}

public class DiffrentMapReadWritePerformanceTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Map<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
//      Map<String, Integer> map = new Hashtable<>();       
//      Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
//      map = Collections.synchronizedMap(map);
        Thread readerThread = new ReaderThread(map);
        Thread writerThread = new WriterThread(map);

        writerThread.start();
        readerThread.start();
        writerThread.join();
        readerThread.join();
        System.out.println(map.get("A"));
    }
}
```

And O/P based on different map objects:
ConcurrentHashMap: 8649407
Hashtable: 5284068
synchronizedMap: 5438039

Hence output proves ConcurrentHashMap is fast relatively to HashTable in multi threaded environment but not prove that while writer thread was writing the reader thread was not blocked for reading. Is there any way to confirm this??

Comment: A call like `map.get("A")` without using the result, does not prove anything. It’s not even required to actually happen at runtime. Further, measured performance is never able to *prove* that something happens under the covers or not. You would have to look into the code of the `ConcurrentHashMap`. Then, you would find that A) there are no segments (since Java 8) and B) `get` indeed does not block.

Answer (score 3):

That JavaDoc comment was written for the earliest version of the class. It provides some implementation flexibility and allowed for evolution.

In a very early version, [size()](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/jsr166/src/main/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java?annotate=1.45#l660) would optimistically sum the segments but fallback to locking to read the counters. Similarly [readValueUnderLock](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/jsr166/src/main/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java?annotate=1.45#l270) was used when the mapping was absent and a check was needed to workaround possible compiler reorderings. That issue, for example, was addressed by the Java Memory Model which was being designed simultaneously to provide guarantees of what the compiler can and couldn't do.

In Java 8 the hash table was redesigned from coarse segments to fine-grained bins. However `computeIfAbsent` was pessimistic by always locking to read or compute the value. In Java 9 this was [improved](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/cgi-bin/viewcvs.cgi/jsr166/src/main/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java?revision=1.323&view=markup#l1691) by avoiding a lock when the entry is at the head of the bin, but locks to scan if not. In cases like a cache this may not be good enough, so Caffeine always performs an optimistic `get` before it the computation. This can have a [dramatic](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine/wiki/Benchmarks#compute) performance gain in those cases.

This means that locking might occur for a retrieval, but it may not as the design evolves to avoid it. The vague wording allows the class contract to remain while the implementation changes.

Answer (score 1):

From my knowledge and I maybe wrong, I would say you are right. The get operation doesn't obtain any lock but it maintains a happens-before order for update. That means that any update that happens-before a get should be reflected in that retrieval. The put operation on the other hand does obtain a lock on a per bin basis where bin is obtained by hashing the object value. So writes/updates to the hashmap require locking. As pointed out in the javadocs though the probability of threads accessing the same bin at the same time is low.

Comment: yes! the get operation is done with happens-before rule because V is declared volatile in Map.Entry in ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: I would say people are usually under the impression that each bin gets locked and thus a read can't proceed, but I don't think that is the case because if you look at the implementation of write it uses a synchronized inside the put but not inside the get.